# Ocaml pattern matching: why this match is not used?

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I just devised a useless function:

```
let rec f = fun x y-> 
    let tmp = f (x-1) y in (match tmp with | y->y|m->m);;
```

Why `m->m` is unused matching? Why `y->y` here actually is a wildcard rather then the value from parameter y?
What I want to do is as the following:

```
let rec f = fun x y ->
    let tmp = f (x-1) y in if tmp=y then y else tmp;;
```

Why the pattern matching one does not work? In answer please address the question rather recommending the imperative way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `when` to overcome it.

```
let rec f = fun x y-> 
    let tmp = f (x-1) y in (match tmp with |_ when tmp = y->y|m->m);;
```

Comment: a simple if is enough when you test the values, match is more interesting for test the patterns of data structures

Comment: @Aldrik Yeah. No offensive, I know when it is appropriate to use match. I have to use match in this case for some non-technical reasons.

Answer (score 3):

The `y` in `match tmp with y -> y | m -> m` is a (new) variable. It thus matches any value.

Try evaluating this expression:

```
(fun x -> match x with y -> y + 1 | w -> w + 2) 3;;
```

The result is `4`: the `x` binds to `3` when the function is applied; the `3` matches against the variable `y`; and, finally, the subexpression `y + 1` evaluates to 4 in the context `[ x = 3; y = 3]`.

The subexpression `if tmp=y then y else tmp` is equivalent to simply `tmp`.

Why do you want to pattern match on an integer?
What is your function supposed to do?